# Azure Devops pipeline that export VM details(subscription, resource group, spn, vm-name, with window operating system SKU) from Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, virtual-machine

Azure Devops pipeline that export VM details(subscription, resource group, spn, vm-name, with window operating system SKU) from Azure portal
using azure devops extract vm information from azure potal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export the VM details via Azure DevOps pipeline, you could leverage the [Azure PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) in the pipeline, then in the task, use [`Get-AzVM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-6.6.0) command to get the details of the VM.

```
Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -Name "VirtualMachine07"

ResourceGroupName        : ResourceGroup11
Id                       : /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/ResourceGroup11/providers/M
icrosoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VirtualMachine07
VmId                     : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Name                     : VirtualMachine07
Type                     : Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
Location                 : eastus
Tags                     : {"creationSource":"acs-VirtualMachine07"}
AvailabilitySetReference : {Id}
DiagnosticsProfile       : {BootDiagnostics}
Extensions               : {linuxdiagnostic, waitforleader}
HardwareProfile          : {VmSize}
NetworkProfile           : {NetworkInterfaces}
OSProfile                : {ComputerName, AdminUsername, LinuxConfiguration, Secrets}
ProvisioningState        : Succeeded
StorageProfile           : {ImageReference, OsDisk, DataDisks}
```